# Need some advice to choose the proper container

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to design a task scheduler to a game engine. A task could be an animation, a trigger controller, etc.

My problem is what container to choose. The idea is: when you insert a new task, the container must reorder and put the task in the proper place. Once executed, task could change and be scheduled again or deleted. This is mainly push and pop.

But, if possible, it would be nice if I could have random access to an element, but not vital. No matter if the container supports one or more elements with the same key.

I think that priority queue fits my needs but I saw that is based on vector implementation, and I think that this container must be somehow  optimized to push and pop.

Opinions?

Comment: In what way will you usually access this queue? Will you sort it often? If/when you iterate through it, will you access each task upon the iteration? Will you do the same upon sort? The tasks - are they pointers or are they actual instantiations of the tasks?

Comment: Well, the way I'm planning to use this system is: you create a task and you insert this task into the system (this is a push). Add tasks would be so frequent. Then, for each frame you check if it need to be executed in this frame, take this tasks (pop) if necessary, you need to execute task, check if is periodic and schedule (push) if needed. My only problem (little) is to find tasks to destroy under demand, but I have an idea of how to solve. The task are instantations because a task contain a functor of the object to execute true functionallity

Comment: Hmm ok, so if you want the push'es to be a sorted-insert (which I guess it is since I assume that you have some sort of priority in your queue... right?) and your data is relatively light-weight (a functor), perhaps some cache-friendly (remember: keep your data close) binary-tree would be appropriate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Containers]
<sub>(source: [adrinael.net](http://adrinael.net/containerchoice))</sub>

(original source: [Liam Devine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170427104755/http://www.liamdevine.co.uk:80/code/containers.php))

Comment: Ey, I wanted to post that! :< But Google's taking too long to load the picture...

Comment: What is the source on this?  (I'm assuming you didn't make it Tomalak)

Comment: @ChrisA: Original source unknown. I suppose I'd better add that in, actually.

Comment: Note that this is only valid for containers with a large number of elements---very large, in some cases.  For simple types (pointers to tasks, for example), `std::vector` is better than `std::list` for anything less than a couple of thousand elements, even when inserting at a random location, and `std::vector` might be better than `std::deque` for a couple of tens of elements, even when inserting in front (but that's less certain).  If the `std::vector` is maintained as a heap (as it is in priority queue), then it is definitely better than `std::list`, and likely even than `std::deque`.

Comment: @James: Yes, the diagram describes _growth_ in computational requirements in `N`, not absolute comparisons for any specific high or low `N`.

Comment: @Tomalak And the diagram isn't relevant to his use, since he's talking about something implementing a priority queue.  (It's also arguable how useful it is in general.  I regularly use `std::vector` instead of `std::list`, even when I'm inserting into the middle, because the allocations and the lack of locality of `std::list` kill me, and if the type involved isn't too complicated, shifting a lot of data isn't too expensive.)

Comment: -1: I don't like how this seems to default to a `deque` rather than a `vector`.  Also doesn't take in to account the need for contigious storage.  Pretty chart but, ultimately, I think it gives bad advice.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Huh? It doesn't "default" to anything.

Comment: @Tomalak:  Sure it does.  Consider a basic use case.  You have a function which formats up strings, one string per line to output to the screen.  On the order of 50 strings or so, maybe 100 characters per line.  The function will be called once per minute, and executes in about 3 nanoseconds.  You want to plop them in to a container one at a time as you build them, then at the end flatten them all to a single string with a `'\n'` between each one.  Which container should you use?  The diagram says `stack`, but there is no compelling reason to use a `stack` in this case.

Comment: OK, that didn't illustrate how "it defaults to a deque" but it did illustrate how it gives what in my view is incorrect advice.

Answer (score 3):

A [priority queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/) seems to be the best option for you.

As you can see, the pop functions has a constant complexity and the push function is logarithmic in time.

Answer (score 2):

std::vector is pretty good for this task, especially if the "steady-state" size of the container remains reasonably constant (you have a number of tasks on the queue doesn't differ widely).

If you need an updatable queue (and std::priority_queue is not), I would suggest you use the d_ary_heap_indirect (which can be found in the Boost.Graph "detail" folder). This is a priority queue used a lot for Dijkstra and A* algorithms that require an updatable priority queue. Random-access is necessary, anyways. Also, using an indirect makes the insertion and deletion from the queue quite efficient. Finally, you can choose your container (as a template argument), but it has to be random-access (so, you can try either vector or deque). Pop is constant-time, push and/or update is log-time, and the proper choice of container will make the container insertion constant-amortized (and the d_ary_heap_indirect amortizes a second time as well, so I wouldn't worry about that).

Answer (score 1):

The vector is optimized for push and pop at one end. :-)

To prioritize you will have to sort the tasks. A vector isn't that bad, if the number of objects is reasonably small, even if it means copying objects during the sort.

Other containers, like linked lists, instead suffer from the need to allocate a new node for each object.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the container type you want with `std::priority_queue`.
However: you're storing pointers (I presume, since it sounds like what you're is
polymorphic and has identity), so copying is cheap.  You're managing it
as a heap (that's what `std::priority_queue` does), so insertions are done
using `push_back` and a number of swaps (lg(n) max).  I can't see any
reason to even consider another structure than `std::vector`.

`std::priority_queue` does hide all of the direct access operators (e.g.
`operator[]`).  It does this because if you modify an entry, you're
likely to invalidate the heap (which is a class invariant of the class).
If you do want to provide direct read access, however, the underlying
container is only `protected`, not `private`, so you can derive from it
and add the operators you want.  I'd very much limit it to `const`
operators, however.

Comment: I think I wont use polymorphic. I'll use a class task that contains a pointer to function or a functor to execute de actual task. There is where I'll use polymorphics.

Comment: The issue here is whether you can copy and assign task, and if so, how expensive it is to copy, assign or swap.  (Consider an explicit specialization of std::swap<Task> if appropriate; that's what the heap management will use.)  If swapping a task becomes very expensive, `std::priority_queue` becomes less interesting.

Comment: Mmmmm, maybe its a good time to consider the use of an object pool and pointers for the swap class. Then move or copy must to be cheap. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how often you're going to be adding tasks and pulling tasks off (and presumably executing them) and how many there are.

If you're going to have tons of little tasks, then prefer priority queue because the cost of node allocation will probably not hurt you as much as the asymptotic growth of n log n for the sort.

If you're going to have a small number of tasks that constantly keep changing priority, then sorting a vector might be reasonable, but you want to use an sorting algorithm that works well when the list is almost sorted.

Scheduling is an art though and you're going to have to profile it once you build it.  There's probably too little information at this point so say.  I'd lean towards a priority queue, but keep other options in mind if performance isn't adequate.

Comment: Is not about to change priority. It's all about to execute and re-schedule: for example, if a task is executed every 10 frames, you execute, change a value like next_frame_to_exectue and schedule again. But this is like reorder. As you say, I'm currently not know if it would be a huge number of task to execute, so I willkeep an eye to performace. Thanks!!!!