# Define a compare function for std::map which uses values instead of keys

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, compare, stdmap

I can define a compare class for a map like this:

```
struct classcomp {
    bool operator() (const string& lhs, const string& rhs) const
    {
        if(lhs < rhs)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
};
```

but here `lhs` and `rhs` represent keys. What if I want to compare by values instead of key?
How will I do that?

Comment: Can you use a multimap and switch key and value?

Comment: Use the keys passed to retrieve the values from the map?

Comment: [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: That compare class doesn't work. What about when `lhs >= rhs`?

Comment: @ahenderson I guess I can try that.

Comment: @crush How do I retrive the values using key inside the compare class?

Comment: @FredLarson `return false` in that case. Should have written than.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Can you provide a simple description of the problem you are trying to solve and how 'comparing by values instead of keys' would help? As it stands the question does not make much sense, *key* is what is used to compare, whether it is part of the value or not is another issue.

Comment: @Jatin: Yes. `return lhs < rhs;` would be more concise. But isn't this just the default comparison anyway?

Comment: @FredLarson He doesn't want to compare lhs to rhs. He wants to compare the value in some arbitrary map, corresponding to the key of lhs to the same of rhs. I think his code is just filler for the moment?

Comment: Or consider using a set, where the key *is* the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about what *you* want; it's about what `std::map` wants. The ordering is based on the layout of elements in memory (usually in a tree structure) and it is this process that uses the comparator. Wishing this were not the case does not make it so!

It sounds to me like `std::map` as a container choice does not fit your requirements. Consult a container choice flow chart to decide what to do next.

Comment: Flowchart link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010097/general-use-cases-for-c-containers

Comment: Yep and http://stackoverflow.com/a/471461/560648 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/6215960/560648 :D

Answer (score 3):

The std::map type does not support comparison by values.  If you want to compare by value, you should consider making a new multimap whose keys represent values in the old map and whose values represent keys in the old map.

That said, it sounds like you're trying to reorder the keys dynamically based on their values.  In that case, you might want to look at priority queues supporting decrease-key, since that might be more aligned with what you're trying to do.

Hope this helps!

Comment: All wrapped up nicely in [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).